# Chrome crashes on uploading files > 1.5 GB with resumablejs in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, resumablejs

I am using resumablejs library with Angular 7. When trying to upload files using resumable, it works till 1.5 GB without any issue, but when file size > 1.5 GB, it works in some cases and crashes in some cases. Not sure what is causing the issue.
It works fine without any issue on Firefox.
How can i make it work with Chrome.

Below is the component. Here we are calculating file size and then displaying it on screen.

```
    export class ResumableAttachmentComponent
        implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges, OnInit {
        @Output() fileSuccess = new EventEmitter<any>();
        @Output() fileError = new EventEmitter<any>();
        @Output() error = new EventEmitter<any>();
        @Output() progress = new EventEmitter<any>();
        @Output() pause = new EventEmitter<any>();
        @Output() complete = new EventEmitter<any>();
        @Output() uploadStart = new EventEmitter<any>();
        @Output() uploadCancel = new EventEmitter<any>();
        @Output() fileTypeError = new EventEmitter<any>();
        @Output() removeBannerImage = new EventEmitter<any>();
        @Output() onComponentInit = new EventEmitter<any>();
    
        @Input() allowDirectorySelect = false;
        @Input() maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5; // 5GB
        @Input() maxFiles = 1; // max number of file allowed
        @Input() multiple = false;
        @Input() pausable = false;
    
        @Input() entityType: string;
        @Input() entityIdentifierId: string;
        @Input() categoryId: string;
        @Input() chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // 5 MB per chunk by default
    
        @Input() checkBeforeUpload: () => boolean;
        @Input() showCategory: boolean = true;
        @Input() showUploadButton: boolean = true;
        @Input() showDelete: boolean = false;
        @Input() showUploadMessage: boolean = false;
    
        @Input() fileType: string[] = []; // Allowing for both [extension, .extension, mime/type, mime/*]
        @Input() theme: string = 'full';
    
        @Input() permissionLevel: number;
        @Input() permission: number;
        @Input() bannerAttachment: any = null;
        @Input() isUploadDisabled: any = false;
        @Input() hasThumbnails: boolean = false;
        Permissions = Permissions;
        PermissionLevel = PermissionLevel;
    
        fileSizeGreaterThanMaxAllowed = false;
        numberOfFilesGreaterThanMaxAllowed = false;
    
        // indicate that the upload is paused by user or not
        paused = false;
        progressBarElt: any;
        querySet: boolean = false;
    
        // text to show on the upload button depending on the fact the file upload is paused or not
        uploadBtnText = localize('general_Upload');
        filesToUpload: Resumable.ResumableFile[] = [];
    
        disableUploadButton = true;
        disablePauseButton = true;
        disableCancelButton = true;
    
        isChunking = false;
    
        // @ts-ignore
        resumable: Resumable;
        supportResumable = false;
        currentUser: IUserProfile;
        baseUrl = titanApiUrl;
    
        destroySubject = new Subject<any>();
        showSelectButton: boolean;
        @Input() gridSupport: {
            gridData: SimpleGrid;
            type: 'extend' | null;
            onRowSelect: () => {};
        };
    
        resumableUploadedFiles: IResumableFileData;
        backboneObservable$: Subscription;
        showCommentsDialog: boolean;
        tireComment: string;
    
        constructor(
            private userProfileService: UserProfileService,
            private backbone: BackboneService,
            private eltRef: ElementRef,
            private renderer: Renderer2,
            private notifyService: NotificationService,
            private confirmationService: ConfirmationDialogService,
            private router: Router,
            private userPermissionHelper: UserPermissionHelper,
            private attachmentService: AttachmentService
        ) {
            this.currentUser = this.userProfileService.userProfile;
            // cancel the file upload when user is navigating away from the page that contains the component
            this.router.events
                .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .takeUntil(this.destroySubject.asObservable())
                .subscribe((e: NavigationStart) => {
                    if (this.resumable && this.resumable.isUploading()) {
                        this.cancelUpload();
                    }
                });
            this.showSelectButton = true;
        }
    
        ngOnInit() {
            this.checkPermission();
            this.backboneObservable$ = this.backbone.message.subscribe(item => {
                if (
                    item.type === BBMessageType.Resumable &&
                    item.subtype === BBMessageSubType.Resumable_Files_Attached
                ) {
                    this.resumableUploadedFiles = item.message;
                }
            });
            this.duplicatesDialog.onSubmit = () => {
                this.duplicatesDialog.show = false;
    
                this.resumable.files.forEach(item => {
                    item.resumableObj.opts.query['overwrite'] =
                        this.duplicatesDialog.confirmedOverwrite.indexOf(
                            item.fileName
                        ) >= 0;
                });
            };
            this.onComponentInit.emit(this);
        }
    
        reset() {
            // reset error flags
            this.fileSizeGreaterThanMaxAllowed = false;
            this.numberOfFilesGreaterThanMaxAllowed = false;
            this.removeAllFiles();
    
            this.isChunking = false;
    
            this.paused = false;
            this.uploadBtnText = localize('general_Upload');
    
            //this.hideProgressBar = true
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.progressBarElt, 'width', 0);
    
            this.disableCancelButton = true;
            this.disablePauseButton = true;
            this.disableUploadButton = true;
        }
    
        ngOnDestroy() {
            this.destroySubject.next();
            this.backboneObservable$.unsubscribe();
        }
    
        ngAfterViewInit() {
            if (!this.querySet) {
                this.setResumableQuery();
            }
        }
    
        hasUploadPermission: boolean = true;
    
        ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
            let self = this;
    
            //If Test Template
            if (
                changes.hasOwnProperty('entityIdentifierId') &&
                changes.entityIdentifierId.currentValue
            ) {
                if (!self.querySet) {
                    self.setResumableQuery();
                }
                if (self.resumable) {
                    self.entityIdentifierId =
                        changes.entityIdentifierId.currentValue;
                    self.resumable.opts.query['entityId'] =
                        changes.entityIdentifierId.currentValue;
                    self.resumable.opts.query['entityIdentifierId'] =
                        changes.entityIdentifierId.currentValue;
                }
            }
    
            if (changes.hasOwnProperty('entityType') && self.resumable) {
                self.resumable.opts.query['entityType'] = this.entityType;
            }
    
            //Hijack query to add new/selected category id
            if (changes.hasOwnProperty('categoryId') && self.resumable) {
                self.resumable.opts.query['categoryId'] = this.categoryId;
            }
    
            if (changes.permission && changes.permissionLevel) {
                self.hasUploadPermission = this.userPermissionHelper.checkPermission(
                    this.permission,
                    this.permissionLevel
                );
            }
    
            if (changes.fileType && self.resumable) {
                self.resumable.opts.fileType = this.fileType;
            }
        }
    
        submitComment() {
            this.resumable.opts.query['comment'] = this.tireComment;
            this.resumable.upload();
            this.tireComment = '';
            this.showCommentsDialog = false;
        }
    
        setResumableQuery() {
            let maxFileAllowed = this.multiple ? undefined : this.maxFiles; // undefined => allow to upload multiple file
            //
            // extra parameters to include in the multipart POST with data
            let query = {};
            if (this.entityType) {
                query['entityType'] = this.entityType;
            }
            if (this.entityIdentifierId) {
                query['entityIdentifierId'] = this.entityIdentifierId;
            }
            if (this.categoryId) {
                query['categoryId'] = this.categoryId;
            }
            if (this.hasThumbnails) {
                query['createThumbnail'] = true;
            } else {
                query['createThumbnail'] = false;
            }
    
            let fileUploadOptions: Resumable.ConfigurationHash = {
                target: `${this.baseUrl}ResumableFile/Upload`,
                simultaneousUploads: 1,
                maxFiles: maxFileAllowed,
                chunkSize: this.chunkSize,
                forceChunkSize: true,
                fileParameterName: 'file', // The name of the multipart POST parameter to use for the file chunk
                query,
                headers: {
                    userId: this.currentUser.id,
                    tenantId: this.currentUser.defaultTenantId
                },
                fileType: this.fileType,
                fileTypeErrorCallback: this.onFileTypeError.bind(this)
            };
    
            // @ts-ignore
            this.resumable = new Resumable(fileUploadOptions);
            this.supportResumable = this.resumable.support; // check if the current browser suport resumable
    
            // add event only if the browser support resumable upload
            if (this.supportResumable) {
                this.progressBarElt = this.eltRef.nativeElement.querySelector(
                    '.t-resumable-attachment-progress-bar-indicator'
                );
                let chooseFileBtn;
                if (this.theme === 'icon') {
                    chooseFileBtn = this.eltRef.nativeElement.querySelector(
                        '.icon-theme-resumable'
                    );
                } else {
                    chooseFileBtn = this.eltRef.nativeElement.querySelector(
                        '.choose-file'
                    );
                }
                if (chooseFileBtn) {
                    this.resumable.assignBrowse(
                        chooseFileBtn,
                        this.allowDirectorySelect
                    );
                    this.resumable.assignDrop(
                        this.eltRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.drop-area')
                    );
                } else {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        if (!this.querySet) {
                            this.setResumableQuery();
                        }
                    }, 400);
                    return;
                }
    
                this.setEvents();
            }
            this.querySet = true;
        }
    
        uploadTheFile() {
            if (
                this.checkBeforeUpload &&
                typeof this.checkBeforeUpload === 'function'
            ) {
                let checkResult = this.checkBeforeUpload();
                // start the upload only if the check function return true
                if (checkResult) {
                    // this.onUploadStart()
                    this.resumable.upload();
                }
            } else if (
                this.checkBeforeUpload &&
                typeof this.checkBeforeUpload !== 'function'
            ) {
                throw new Error(
                    "The 'checkBeforeUpload' attribute must be a function."
                );
            } else {
                // this.onUploadStart()
                this.resumable.upload();
                /* temporarily commenting the Comment popup while uploading file for Tire Model Request
                if (this.entityType == 'TireModelSpecs') {
                    this.showCommentsDialog = true;
                } else {
                this.resumable.upload();
                }*/
            }
        }
    
        pauseFile() {
            this.resumable.pause();
        }
    
        cancelUpload() {
            this.resumable.cancel();
        }
    
        private setEvents() {
            this.resumable.on('error', this.onError.bind(this));
            this.resumable.on('fileError', this.onFileError.bind(this));
            this.resumable.on('pause', this.onPause.bind(this));
            this.resumable.on('complete', this.onComplete.bind(this));
            this.resumable.on('fileSuccess', this.onFileSuccess.bind(this));
            this.resumable.on('cancel', this.onUploadCancel.bind(this));
            this.resumable.on('uploadStart', this.onUploadStart.bind(this));
            //this.resumable.on('uploadStart', this.startUploadAfterCheckIsOk)
            this.resumable.on('fileProgress', this.onProgress.bind(this));
            this.resumable.on('fileAdded', this.onFileAdded.bind(this));
            this.resumable.on('chunkingStart', this.onChunkingStart.bind(this));
            this.resumable.on(
                'chunkingComplete',
                this.onChunkingComplete.bind(this)
            );
        }
    
        @Output() onFileAdd = new EventEmitter();
        private onFileAdded(file: ResumableFile, event) {
            this.numberOfFilesGreaterThanMaxAllowed = false;
            this.fileSizeGreaterThanMaxAllowed = false;
            this.isDragOver = false;
    
            //Getting Preview Image
            let resumableFile: ResumableFile = this.resumable.files.find(item => {
                // @ts-ignore
                return file.file.uniqueIdentifier === item.uniqueIdentifier;
            });
            // @ts-ignore
            resumableFile.fileReader = new FileReader();
            // @ts-ignore
            resumableFile.fileReader.readAsDataURL(file.file);
            /**
             * Show preview only if MIME type is of image type
             */
            if (resumableFile.file.type.startsWith('image')) {
                resumableFile.isPreviewSupported = true;
            }
    
            /**
             * TODO: Check if total size was being looked at here..
             */
            // @ts-ignore
            if (this.resumable.getSize() > this.maxFileSize) {
                this.fileSizeGreaterThanMaxAllowed = true;
                this.filesToUpload = [...this.resumable.files];
            } else if (
                !this.multiple &&
                this.resumable.files &&
                this.resumable.files.length > this.maxFiles
            ) {
                this.numberOfFilesGreaterThanMaxAllowed = true;
            } else {
                this.filesToUpload = [...this.resumable.files]; // get the updated list of files to upload
                this.disableUploadButton = false;
                this.renderer.setStyle(this.progressBarElt, 'width', 0);
            }
            this.disableCancelButton = false;
    
            if (this.theme === 'icon') {
                this.uploadTheFile();
            } else {
                this.duplicatesDialog.duplicatesArray = [];
                this.checkForDuplicates();
            }
    
            this.setRealLastModifiedDate(resumableFile, file.file.lastModified);
            this.onFileAdd.emit(this.filesToUpload);
        }
    
        setRealLastModifiedDate(file: ResumableFile, dateMS) {
            file['resumableObj'].opts.query['documentLastModifiedByDate'] = moment(
                dateMS
            ).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm');
        }
    
        duplicatesDialog: {
            duplicatesArray: any[];
            confirmedOverwrite: any[];
            show: boolean;
            onSubmit: any;
        } = {
            duplicatesArray: [],
            confirmedOverwrite: [],
            show: false,
            onSubmit: () => {}
        };
    
        checkForDuplicates() {
            if (
                this.resumableUploadedFiles &&
                this.currentUser.tenantFeatureMap.overwriteFile &&
                this.resumableUploadedFiles.categoryId === this.categoryId &&
                this.resumableUploadedFiles.entityIdentifierId ===
                    this.entityIdentifierId
            ) {
                this.filesToUpload.forEach(item => {
                    if (
                        this.resumableUploadedFiles.data.indexOf(item.fileName) >= 0
                    ) {
                        this.duplicatesDialog.duplicatesArray.push(item.fileName);
                    } else {
                        item['resumableObj'].opts.query['overwrite'] = false;
                    }
                });
            }
    
            if (this.duplicatesDialog.duplicatesArray.length > 0) {
                this.duplicatesDialog.show = true;
            }
        }
    
        private onPause() {
            this.paused = true;
            this.disableUploadButton = false;
            this.uploadBtnText = localize('general_Resume');
            this.pause.emit();
        }
    
        onComplete() {
            this.complete.emit();
            //Reset filesToUpload after completion
            this.removeAllFiles();
        }
    
        OnRemoveBannerImg() {
            this.confirmationService.setConfirm({
                message: localize('general_ConformMessageForDelete'),
                header: localize('general_Delete'),
                accept: () => {
                    this.removeBannerImage.emit();
                },
                reject: () => {}
            });
        }
    
        // `message`  is the response body from the server.
        private onFileSuccess(file: ResumableFile, message: any) {
            if (this.showUploadMessage) {
                this.notifyService.notify({
                    severity: 'success',
                    summary: localize('general_Success'),
                    detail: localize('general_MessageSuccessFileUploaded')
                });
            }
    
            this.filesToUpload = [];
            this.fileSuccess.emit({ file, message });
    
            this.disableCancelButton = true;
            this.disablePauseButton = true;
            this.disableUploadButton = true;
        }
    
        // error on a specific file
        private onFileError(file: ResumableFile, message: any) {
            this.fileError.emit({ file, message });
        }
    
        // general error
        private onError(message: any, file: ResumableFile) {
            this.error.emit({ file, message });
        }
    
        onUploadStart() {
            //this.hideProgressBar = false
            this.uploadStart.emit(this.resumable.files.length);
    
            this.paused = false;
            this.disableUploadButton = true;
            this.uploadBtnText = localize('general_Upload');
    
            this.disableCancelButton = false;
            this.disablePauseButton = false;
            this.disableUploadButton = true;
        }
    
        private onProgress(file: ResumableFile) {
            let fileClone: any = { ...file };
            fileClone.uploaded = file.progress(false);
            let totalProgress = this.resumable.progress();
            let progressPercentage = Math.floor(totalProgress * 100) + '%';
    
            this.renderer.setStyle(
                this.progressBarElt,
                'width',
                progressPercentage
            );
            this.progress.emit({ file: fileClone, uploaded: totalProgress });
        }
    
        /**
         * return individual file upload progress
         */
        parseProgress(file: ResumableFile) {
            return (
                Math.round(Math.floor(file.progress(false) * 100) * 10) / 10 + '%'
            );
        }
    
        private onUploadCancel() {
            this.paused = false;
            this.uploadBtnText = localize('general_Upload');
            this.filesToUpload = this.resumable.files;
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.progressBarElt, 'width', 0);
            this.uploadCancel.emit();
            this.disableCancelButton = true;
            this.disablePauseButton = true;
            this.disableUploadButton = true;
        }
    
        private removeAllFiles() {
            let copy = [...this.resumable.files];
            copy.forEach((f: any) => this.resumable.removeFile(f));
            this.filesToUpload = this.resumable.files;
            this.duplicatesDialog.confirmedOverwrite = [];
            this.duplicatesDialog.duplicatesArray = [];
        }
    
        private onChunkingStart() {
            this.isChunking = true;
        }
    
        private onChunkingComplete() {
            this.isChunking = false;
        }
    
        private onFileTypeError(file, errorCount) {
            this.fileTypeError.emit({ file, errorCount });
        }
    
        removeFile(file: any) {
            this.resumable.removeFile(file);
            // update the list when a file is removed
            this.filesToUpload = this.resumable.files;
            this.onFileAdd.emit(this.filesToUpload);
        }
    
        getFileSize(sizeInOctet: number) {
            sizeInOctet = +sizeInOctet; // convert to number in case ng pass the value as string
            let KB = 1024;
            let MB = 1024 * 1024;
            let GB = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    
            if (sizeInOctet >= KB) {
                if (sizeInOctet >= MB) {
                    if (sizeInOctet >= GB) {
                        return `${(sizeInOctet / GB).toFixed(2)} GB`;
                    }
                    return `${(sizeInOctet / MB).toFixed(2)} MB`;
                }
                return `${(sizeInOctet / KB).toFixed(2)} KB`;
            }
            return `${sizeInOctet} Bytes`;
        }
    
        // case multiple file
    
        // Hide pause/resume when the upload has completed
        // Show pause, hide resume on upload start
    
        isDragOver: boolean = false;
        onDrop($event) {
            this.isDragOver = false;
        }
    
        allowDrop($event) {
            this.isDragOver = true;
        }
    
        onLeave() {
            this.isDragOver = false;
        }
    
        hasAccess: boolean = false;
        hasReadAccess: boolean = false;
        hasDeleteAccess: boolean = false;
        hasCreateAccess: boolean = false;
        checkPermission() {
            if (
                this.permission &&
                this.permissionLevel &&
                this.entityIdentifierId &&
                this.entityType
            ) {
                this.hasDeleteAccess =
                    this.userPermissionHelper.checkPermission(
                        this.permission,
                        PermissionLevel.Delete
                    ) ||
                    this.userPermissionHelper.checkSpecialPermission(
                        this.permission,
                        PermissionLevel.Delete,
                        this.entityIdentifierId,
                        this.entityType
                    );
                this.hasReadAccess =
                    this.userPermissionHelper.checkPermission(
                        this.permission,
                        PermissionLevel.Read
                    ) ||
                    this.userPermissionHelper.checkSpecialPermission(
                        this.permission,
                        PermissionLevel.Read,
                        this.entityIdentifierId,
                        this.entityType
                    );
                this.hasCreateAccess =
                    this.userPermissionHelper.checkPermission(
                        this.permission,
                        PermissionLevel.Create
                    ) ||
                    this.userPermissionHelper.checkSpecialPermission(
                        this.permission,
                        PermissionLevel.Create,
                        this.entityIdentifierId,
                        this.entityType
                    );
                this.hasAccess =
                    this.hasCreateAccess ||
                    this.hasDeleteAccess ||
                    this.hasReadAccess;
            }
        }
    
        checkFileList() {
            if (!this.resumable) {
                return !this.isChunking;
            } else {
                return !this.isChunking && !this.resumable.isUploading();
            }
        }
    
        downloadAttachment(id) {
            this.attachmentService.download(id);
        }
    
        viewLog(id) {
            this.attachmentService.getLogByDocumentId;
        }
    
        previewFileUrl: string = '';
        previewDialog: boolean = false;
        expandImage(previewFileUrl) {
            this.previewFileUrl = previewFileUrl;
            this.previewDialog = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're more likely to a get a helpful answer if you post the error message that you're getting. Code would help too, or better yet, a simple working example (e.g. stackblitz)

Comment: when is your chunk size? when you are trying to upload chunks.

Comment: please visit this [link](https://github.com/23/resumable.js/issues/220) for more clarification about chrome crashes due to resumablejs.

Comment: chunk size is 5 MB. Above link did not provide fruitful response

Comment: I would try [background fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/background-fetch), you can split blobs into smaller chunks if you got a unstable internet connection or if you want to do other stuff in the meanwhile, like leaving the page, close the phone and put it in your pocket.